# Fail2Ban Apache-noscript failing to block script as referer

Tags: fail2ban

I am receiving a number of `apache` not found or unable to stat and would like to block these IP addresses using Fail2Ban.

```
[Fri Feb 28 03:36:51.816955 2014] [:error] [pid 29027] [client XX.X.XX.XX:1432] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: http://redstonewither.com/wp-login.php
```

I have the Fail2Ban filter called `apache-noscript` enabled which includes the following failregex:

```
failregex = [[]client HOST[]] (File does not exist|script not found or unable to stat): /\S*(\.php|\.asp|\.exe|\.pl)
```

I think the above is blocking these:

```
[Wed Feb 26 21:58:38.695327 2014] [:error] [pid 1390] [client XX.XX.XXX.XXX:36422] script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat
```

Would I be correct in saying the following `failregex` would block the referrer ones?

```
failregex = [[]client HOST[]] (File does not exist|script not found or unable to stat, referrer:): /\S*(\.php|\.asp|\.exe|\.pl)
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/577566/fail2ban-not-blocking-brute-force-attack-on-dovecot) Q/A. There is a brief explanation on how to test your `failregex` configuration.

Comment: The link provided has nothing to do with my issue.

Comment: IMHO, the link provided does show how to test your regexes, and therefore should be valuable information when trying to answer: "Would I be correct in saying the following failregex would block the referrer ones?".

Comment: @daygle: You need to read the answer to the linked question, it provides useful information on how to test your regex against your log entries.